# Button and animated transition between normal / selected / pressed states

Tags: android

Android Button changes its background drawable when it moves between different states (normal, pressed, selected, disabled). The background switch is instant. Is it posible to make it smooth (animated)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. You simply `addAnimation()` for button. 4 animations that are supported: translate, rotate, alpha, scale. I guess you know them.

Comment: Thanks, my question was perhaps too vague, I was trying to find out if it is possible without doing the animations manually, which is too much work.